# Отображение юникода

Tags: c#, перекодировка, unicode

Есть юникод-строка, например: \u041d\u0435\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u0438\u043b\u044c\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u043b\u043e\u0433\u0438\u043d \u0438\u043b\u0438 \u043f\u0430\u0440\u043e\u043b\u044c. Как ее преобразовать чтобы вывести, допустим, в MessadgeBox? Пробовал вот так:

```
var a = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.Default, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s));
MessageBox.Show(Encoding.Default.GetString(a));
```

Не выходит.

Comment: это json формат вроде, гугли для jsona

Comment: `System.String` *всегда* содержит строку в UTF-16LE (при нормальных условиях). `MessageBox.Show()` принимает `System.String`, в чём проблема?

Comment: Если ему отдать просто эту строку он ее в таком виде и выведет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже указано Данилом в комментариях, при выводе в MessageBox преобразовывать строку не нужно.

Если же все-таки это необходимо, то можно так:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape("\u041d\u0435\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u0438\u043b\u044c\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u043b\u043e\u0433\u0438\u043d \u0438\u043b\u0438 \u043f\u0430\u0440\u043e\u043b\u044c");
```

Comment: Работает! Благодарю за помощь:) Я всегда думал что для таких целей и существует класс Encoding. Через него, все-таки, возможно сделать преобразование?

Comment: Вообще класс Encoding существует для несколько других целей, в частности перевода строк определенной кодировки в массив байтов и обратно, а также перекодировки строк из одной кодировки в другую. Думаю, что сделать необходимое Вам преобразование через класс Encoding нельзя. 
Если не прав, буду рад услышать мнение знающих людей.