# Преобразование в юникод

Tags: c#, unicode

В продолжении [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/111586/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0). А как мне преобразовать текст уже в обратную сторону. Из переменной типа string в формат \uxxxx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
var str = "тест";
var escaped = string.Join("", str.Select(c => "\\u" + ((int)c).ToString("x4")));
```